# Virtual monitors on single monitor

Tags: testing, virtualization, monitor

Our application is to display different things on different monitors at the same time. One of them is a touch screen and another a typical monitor. I'm somehow forced to develop this in an environment with only one monitor. Is there any way to simulate two monitors in an environment with only one monitor? I thought that this would be easy with some virtualization software but I couldn't find anything like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the answer you were looking for? I have asked a similar question, and the answer you seek might be here [here](http://superuser.com/questions/369702/splitting-one-giant-monitor-as-if-it-was-two).
Using virtualization you would create unnecessary overhead with the extra OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be VirtualBox could help? It [supports multiple monitor guest systems](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-display) even if there are less monitors on the host.